# From SQL to Access linked table issues - ODBC fail

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, odbc

I am developing form in MS access. I use SELECT function to load the data to the form.  When I am creating a SQL-linked table (External data, ODBC database ..), I am getting error '3146 ODBC -- call failed'. But when I am importing the table with no link to SQL, it works.

Other select functions work with linked table fine.

```
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim rs_Change_Control As Recordset

    CustId = Me.txt_ID.Value
    If Len(CustId) > 0 Then

       Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT a.key, a.date 
        FROM (SELECT gnr.key, gnr.date
            FROM gnr) a 
                INNER JOIN (SELECT key, MAX(date) AS maxtime 
                FROM gnr GROUP BY key) b 
            ON a.key = b.key AND a.date = b.maxtime WHERE a.key = '123456789';")
If rs.EOF = False Then
Me.txt_ID.Value = rs!key
    End if
```

Comment: There is no need to have semi colon at the end of query.

Comment: First and foremost, please specify the ODBC database. SQL is a programming language which even Access uses! So an SQL linked table is not specific. Did you mean SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? Oracle? All of which Access can connect to. Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Second, the code posted is not linking an external database table with ODBC but calling a recordset in local Access database. Please add the problem section. Also, add [DB.engine error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/161288) in your error handle for more informative error message instead of generic "ODBC call failed."

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your quotes in query,

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SELECT a.key, a.date 
    FROM ("SELECT gnr.key, gnr.date
        FROM gnr) a 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT key, MAX(date) AS maxtime 
            FROM gnr GROUP BY key) b 
        ON a.key = b.key AND a.date = b.maxtime WHERE a.key = '123456789'";)
```

should be

```
 Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT a.key, a.date 
    FROM (SELECT gnr.key, gnr.date
        FROM gnr) a 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT key, MAX(date) AS maxtime 
            FROM gnr GROUP BY key) b 
        ON a.key = b.key AND a.date = b.maxtime WHERE a.key = '123456789'")
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake here, but in the code it is as supposed to be. So, this is not an issue.

Comment: @user2702405 you have extra semi colon in the code.

Comment: @user2702405 [Refer this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/160762)
"Search the computer for the Odbc.dll file, and verify the version in File Manager. You can do this by clicking on the file and then clicking Properties on the File menu. If the first possible Odbc.dll file in the path is the ODBC 1.x Driver Manager, you are most likely encountering the problem.

you should remove the ODBC 1.x Driver Manager (Odbc.dll) from the path and/or place the ODBC 2.x Driver Manager (Odbc.dll) in the path first."

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the issue, but `date`is a reserved word.
Try enclosing it in square brackets: `a.[date]`, `MAX([date])` etc wherever it appears.

If possible, rename the column. It will create problems again and again.